# How can I utilize the driver node GPU with Horovod on an Azure Databricks cluster?

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, horovod

When I create a cluster with one driver + two workers, with one GPU each, and try to launch training on each GPU I would write:

```
from sparkdl import HorovodRunner 
hr = HorovodRunner(np=3) 
hr.run(train_hvd)
```

But receive the following error message:

```
HorovodRunner was called with np=3, which is greater than the maximum processes that can be placed
on this cluster. This cluster can place at most 2 processes on 2 executors. Training won't start
until there are enough workers on this cluster. You  can increase the cluster size or cancel the
current run and retry with a smaller np.
```

Apparently HorovodRunner does not consider the GPU on the driver node (correct?). When I use the options np=-1 (driver GPU only), np=2 (2 GPUs somewhere), or np=-2 (driver-only but with 2 GPUs) everything works fine, i.e. there is nothing functionally wrong with my code, besides that I cannot get it to utilize all 3 available GPUs.

(a) Is there a way to make Horovod include the GPUs on the driver node in distributed learning?

(b) Alternatively: is there a way to create a cluster with GPU workers but a non-GPU driver in Databricks?

Answer (score 0):

To run HorovodRunner on the driver only with n subprocesses, use hr = HorovodRunner(np=-n). For example, if there are 4 GPUs on the driver node, you can choose n up to 4.

**Parameters: np –**
number of parallel processes to use for the Horovod job. This argument only takes effect on Databricks Runtime 5.0 ML and above. It is ignored in the open-source version. On Databricks, each process will take an available task slot, which maps to a GPU on a GPU cluster or a CPU core on a CPU cluster. Accepted values are:

**If <0**, this will spawn -np subprocesses on the driver node to run Horovod locally. Training stdout and stderr messages go to the notebook cell output, and are also available in driver logs in case the cell output is truncated. This is useful for debugging and we recommend testing your code under this mode first. However, be careful of heavy use of the Spark driver on a shared Databricks cluster. Note that np < -1 is only supported on Databricks Runtime 5.5 ML and above.

**If >0**, this will launch a Spark job with np tasks starting all together and run the Horovod job on the task nodes. It will wait until np task slots are available to launch the job. If np is greater than the total number of task slots on the cluster, the job will fail. As of Databricks Runtime 5.4 ML, training stdout and stderr messages go to the notebook cell output. In the event that the cell output is truncated, full logs are available in stderr stream of task 0 under the 2nd spark job started by HorovodRunner, which you can find in the Spark UI.

**If 0**, this will use all task slots on the cluster to launch the job.

You can find details about the parameter np in the [HorovodRunner API documentation](https://databricks.github.io/spark-deep-learning/docs/_site/api/python/index.html#sparkdl.HorovodRunner) and "[HorovodRunner: Distributed Deep Learning with Horovod](https://docs.databricks.com/applications/deep-learning/distributed-training/horovod-runner.html)".

Hope this helps.